# Android using RecyclerView in fragments with remote data fetch

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I am building my first android application where I will have bottom navigation with three buttons which are attached to fragments. First fragment (**MessageFragment**) is for responsible for listing all messages from the server using Volley and Gson libs.

I am trying to load messages from the server which return **JSON** data in the form.

```
[
 {
  "id": "1",
  "message": "Some message",
  "created_at": "2017-08-23 12:38:31"
 },
 {
 "id": "2",
 "message": "Another message",
 "created_at": "2017-08-23 12:39:28"
 },
 ....
]
```

I have found a good example of RecyclerView in fragment but unfortunately, in this example data is not coming from the remote.

https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.html

Can someone help me to why I am not getting data in the adapter when I using below code?

What should I do to fix it?

Here is my code

**MessageFragment.java**

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment {

 private Context mContext;

 private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://10.0.2.2/message/list?userid=1";
 List<Message> msgs = new ArrayList<Message>();
 private RequestQueue requestQueue;
 private Gson gson;


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.mContext=context;
}

public static MessageFragment newInstance() {
    MessageFragment fragment = new MessageFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.mContext);
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
    gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    fetchMessages();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvMessages);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())); //set layoutManger
    MessageRVAdapter mAdapter = new MessageRVAdapter(msgs);//create an adapter
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);  // set adapter
    return view;
}

private void fetchMessages() {
    System.out.println("Now in fetchMessages");
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

private final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        msgs = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, Message[].class));
        System.out.println("inside " + msgs);
    }
};

private final Response.ErrorListener onPostsError = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        System.out.println("Messages load fail");
        Log.e("PostActivity", error.toString());
    }
};

}
```

**MessageRVAdapter.php**

```
public class MessageRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageRVAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Message> messages;

public MessageRVAdapter(List<Message> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView message;
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvMessage);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message message = messages.get(position);
    holder.message.setText(message.getMessages());
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.rvmessages_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messages.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your *Recycler Adapter* on post loaded.

```
private final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        msgs = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, Message[].class));
        System.out.println("inside " + msgs);
        MessageRVAdapter mAdapter = new MessageRVAdapter(msgs);//create an adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);  // set adapter
    }
};
```

Also may be you need to parse *JSON data* from *onResponse* whatever you need to display parse from *response string* and display it.

Comment: Where is post loaded method?

Comment: @VK321 Check edited answer. This is the *Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded* method.

Comment: Error:(85, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable recyclerView

Comment: @VK321 Definer your *Recycler* view variable globally.

Comment: done.. now ..  E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: This is the problem. oncreateview need adapter but post takes time to get data? so we can make view.... dont know what is the solution.

Comment: Your solution I tried a long time ago with no luck.

Comment: @VK321 Parse the json data properly i think you have not parsed anything from json.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for the quick help. Could please help me how i can add load more data on scroll.. any reference?